# How to match Input to height of container?

Tags: html, css

My goal is to have a reusable number field with customizable increment/decrement buttons. However, my issue is that I cannot make the input field correctly fill the height of the container.

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  outline: auto;
  outline-color: red;
}

input {
  height: 100%;
  width: 75%;
  text-align: center;
}

.button-container { 
  width: 25%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

button {
  height: 50%;
}

input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="number">
  <div class="button-container">
    <button>+</button>
    <button>-</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

My results on the most recent version of Chrome:

[image]

I was unable to find any questions here addressing this specific issue. Any input would be appreciated.

Comment: remove `height:100%` on input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is remove the height from the input as shown below

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  outline: auto;
  outline-color: red;
}

input {
  width: 75%;
  text-align: center;
}

.button-container { 
  width: 25%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

button {
  height: 50%;
}

input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="number">
  <div class="button-container">
    <button>+</button>
    <button>-</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well... I feel silly now. Thank you for the quick answer

Answer (score 1):

There're at leats 3 ways to achieve this:

1. make `input`'s `height: auto` (which is the default) instead of `height: 100%`. Because it's default, you can just remove `height: 100%`
2. add `box-sizing: border-box;` for `input`
3. or manually, add `border: 0; padding: 0;` instead

---

**Explanation:**

From here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing

> By default in the CSS box model, the width and **height you assign to an element** is applied only to the element's **content box**

So `height: 100%` you declared to `input` is calculated as only the `content` part. Meanwhile, `input` has default `padding` and `border`, which added up and made your element look weird.

[image]

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  outline: auto;
  outline-color: red;
}

input {
  height: 100%; /* delete this */
  
  box-sizing: border-box; /* or instead, add this */

  border: 0; /* or these */
  padding: 0;

  width: 75%;
  text-align: center;
}

.button-container { 
  width: 25%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

button {
  height: 50%;
}

input::-webkit-outer-spin-button,
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="number">
  <div class="button-container">
    <button>+</button>
    <button>-</button>
  </div>
</div>
```